# Missing default value of varchar2(4000) column in DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL （oracle 11g）

Tags: oracle11g, ddl

step 1 - create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST1"."JWTEST"
(
  C0 NUMBER(38) not null PRIMARY KEY,
  C1 VARCHAR2(4000) DEFAULT 'abcd...(total 4000 characters)...abcd',
  SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (ALL) COLUMNS
);
```

step 2 - get ddl of the table

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'JWTEST', 'TEST1') FROM DUAL;
```

and I got this:

```
  CREATE TABLE "TEST1"."jwtest2" 
   (    "C0" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "C1" VARCHAR2(4000) DEFAULT , 
     PRIMARY KEY ("C0")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   ) ;
```

As you can see, the default value for the "C1" column has disappeared...What caused it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What caused it?

The query works ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F7unns8z)) with a default 3998 characters long; it does not work with a default 3999 or 4000 characters long.

An educated guess is that the DDL statement is being generated in the procedure and, within the procedure, there is a local variable that stores the `default` value that is defined as a `VARCHAR2(4000)` and it is also storing the quotes around the literal; this means that 2 characters are taken up by the quotes and if the `default` plus surrounding quotes exceeds 4000 bytes then it will raise an exception and the default is omitted from the DDL from the generated statement.

You could:

- Limit your `default` to 3998 characters; or
- Raise a ticket with Oracle, under your support contract, and inform them of the (potential) bug and ask for a solution.